# Is the coefficient of determination (r-squared) a measure of reliability or validity?

Tags: regression, r-squared, reliability

I am working on my thesis where I want to assess the reliability and validity of different regression models. I only have one data set, which means that I cannot train on one data set and test on another to assess reliability or generalizability.

I was wondering whether r-squared (coefficient of determination) is considered a measure of reliability or validity?

I have read about the different reliability coefficients (coefficient of equivalence, coefficient of stability etc.) but there is no clear indication of the coefficient of determination as a reliability measure.

Comment: No, not if used on the same data as was used for training. Usually you would split your "train" set in two parts, or do cross-validation. Why can you not split your data set?

Comment: I have split the data set (train-test)  and i did cross validation (K=5). However i cannot use this model to test it on a different data set because there is only one available. I am looking for a way to measure reliability (besides validity).

Comment: So you did do cross-validation, then why not use the CV $R^2$ score?